# Drupal: passing 3 arguments with views?

Tags: php, drupal, view

Im having a hard time passing 3 taxonomies terms with views, in my case its:

Car Make (ex: ford )
Car Model (ex: explorer )
Car Category (ex: engine )

So, how would I display a node that has the terms Ford, Explorer and Engine assigned to it?

Comment: Not sure if i understand... you want to know the settings for a view - is it field type view? There is a field "taxonomy -> all terms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a taxonomy term filter multiple times, or you can set the filter to be 'multiple select'. Same goes for arguments, you can add a taxonomy term ID argument multiple times.